A movie about two friends who planned to kill each other's wives
I saw this movie around 2006 on a DVD. It was not a mainstream movie. I believe it is a hollywood production, but must be a direct to DVD.
The plot begins when the body of a woman is discovered and police arrest a man (might be her husband or his friend). Anyways, the arrested man says that he did not kill her and that his friend did kill her, and says: "He [my friend] is gunna say that I did it, but he is the one who did it".
The majority of the film is set inside a court room and the attorney/lawyer discovers at the end that these 2 men decided that they were fed up with their wives and wanted to get rid of them, but will surely be suspected of murder if they did the killing. So they decided to kill each other's wives to distance them selves from suspicion. However, something wrong happened and the plan was half committed or something like that. 

Sounds like some loose adaptation of Strangers On A Train, but I can't think of a Hollywood one made around that time. Was it from the 2000s?

It's not (Strangers on a train). the movie might have been made in the 90s. But I only watched it in 2006 @Walt

The '90s had a lot of erotic thrillers which had some plot similarities. Anything else you can remember about the principle characters?

It is not an erotic film. Can't remember any other details, sorry. @moviegique

Possibly Murder Between Friends (1994)

@dbugger yes it is! Thanks a lot. If you could post that as an answer, I will accept it

Looks like the  Made for TV Movie Murder Between Friends (1994), starring thirtysomething's Timothy Busfield.

By night, a woman is found dead in her place, where she was with her
  husband and a friend (her husband's best friend). After fighting, the
  two friends accuse each other of committing the crime, relating
  different versions of the events to the police and later in court.
  Who's lying? Who's telling the truth? What really happened that
  night...?

